# Stop Quartz Job on local machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, quartz-scheduler

Friends,

I am running some quartz jobs on my application. Everything is working fine, the only thing that I want to do is not to run jobs when I am using that application on my local machine. It means that jobs should only run on server, and run on local only when I want them to.

I know there can be a solution to add a boolean constant, if that is true than run otherwise jobs will not run, but how and where to do it?

Also if there is some other thing that can be done?

```
public class JobScheduler
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

            scheduler.Start();

            IJobDetail offersRefreshJob = JobBuilder.Create<OffersRefreshJob>().Build();

            ITrigger triggerForOffersRefreshJob = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
              (s =>
                 s.WithIntervalInMinutes(8)
                .OnEveryDay()
                .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(0, 0))
              )
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(offersRefreshJob, triggerForOffersRefreshJob);
    }
}
```

This is the code of Global.asax.cs file. I have used a boolean RUN_JOBS variable, and called start() only if RUN_JOBS is true, but it still is running jobs on my local machine. It is an ASP.net MVC web application.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public bool RUN_JOBS = true;
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            if (RUN_JOBS)
            {
                JobScheduler.Start();
            }            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you running it locally for debugging purposes? Can you post your code for the scheduler?

Comment: @Seany84 I have added the code of my scheduler, Yes I am running for debugging purposes, also I dont want it to refresh all my local data, I want to refresh data on my local data when I need, not automatically. There are many such jobs, I have posted code of just one.

Comment: 1. Where do you call your `Start()` from and can you post that code too? 2. Is Quartz running in a console application or Windows service ?

Comment: @Seany84 Added the code. Start() is called inside Global.asax.cs class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code is running locally, I assume it is in `Debug` mode and when you deploy to your server it is in `Release` mode.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);


        #if !DEBUG
            JobScheduler.Start();
        #endif            
    }
}
```

Comment: makes sense. Will mark as an answer after verifying. Thanks  for your time. :)

Comment: @Seany84 In this case, can we use #if !DEBUG #endif  for all of the similar situation in Visual Studio?

Comment: @binary You can use it wherever you like, as long as you run in `Debug` locally and `Release` mode when you deploy to your server.